# Тернарный оператор Laravel Blade

Tags: laravel

Как в Laravel в шаблонизаторе сократить код такого вида, как работает тернарный оператор?

```
<?php if(isset($data->name)) { echo $data->name; } else { echo 'Null'; }; ?>
```

Comment: Ну вы попробовали что-нибудь? Или ждете когда вам все напишут. Пример - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25284344/ternary-in-laravel-blade

Answer (score 2):

```
{{ $data->name ? $data->name : Null }}
```